# Image Button causing postback instead of calender extender popup using AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendar, asp.net-ajax

I am using ajax calender extender to pickup date, but whenever I click on image button to popup calender, it is causing postback. I am doing as follows:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ToolTip="Last Date" CssClass="g2"</asp:TextBox> 
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="26px" width="30px" ImageUrl="~/images/cal.jpg"></asp:ImageButton>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
 Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDate" PopupButtonID ="ImageButton1"></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

I am confused, as I never encountered such scenerio before .

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use it like this ,why are you using button for the calender extender.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  

<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1"  TargetControlID="txtStartDate"  runat="server"/>
```

Comment: having calender popup on click on textbox is not user friendly i guess

Comment: why? ,FYI you can use jquery calender it is much better the this one.